# Retrieve another user's query results in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, salesforce

So, me and my teammate are in a situation where our QA team off-shore has left a stored procedure running after-hours and went home for the day. Because of the time zone differential, me and my teammate have now seen the job has finished -- however, we have no way of seeing whether it was successful or not, because the messages are returned to our QA team member's client instead of ours.

My question is this: Is there some way that I can retrieve the message results from that stored procedure execution remotely? Or will we have to wait until tomorrow to hear back from our QA team?

There is a complication in that the stored procedure in question runs against a linked server that is *not* a Microsoft SQL server. Therefore I can't go to the linked server and check on previous activity using the tools that SQL Server Management Studio provides. The linked server in question is a Salesforce org, so if anyone has any suggestions regarding finding past query activity in SF, that would also be helpful. However, I have looked myself and wasn't able to find anything relevant there either.

Comment: Unless there is some logging in the procedure there isn't much of anything you can do. Assuming you aren't running a trace. You can't pull messages sent to one client from another even in real time, let alone after the fact.

Comment: Yeah... that is what I was thinking. It doesn't seem like a practical feature to have on by default.

Comment: You could add 'results' table to your database and add few lines to store proc to insert results there before returning them.

Comment: I'm aware of many different solutions that would work had we actually planned this ahead, I'm looking specifically for some way to pull the results that you would receive after running a query in SQL Server Management Studio 1.) after the query has already executed and 2.) from another user's client/connection. If that is not possible, so be it, but I'm only looking for that specific solution.

Comment: Then I am afraid you are going to be disappointed. You can't add logging after something has happened. The only way is if you had something in place already.